# How to ignore case when running Unmatched query (Wizard) in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I get records with case difference when run Unmatched Query wizard in ms access

Is there way to get rid of case sensitiveness there

Cheers

Shabar

Answer (score 0):

convert the search term and the column to upper (or lower) case, similar to:

```
WHERE UCASE(column1) = UCASE(?)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply cha. Basically I run unmatched Query Wizard between full and NotMatch. Following is the SQL script and the result
'code' SELECT full.[Doc Name], full.[WPR], full.[Source Doc Name], full.[WP]
FROM [full] LEFT JOIN NotMatch ON full.[WPR]= NotMatch.[WP]
WHERE (((NotMatch.[WP]) Is Null)); 'code'                            
'Doc Name WPR  Source Doc Name WP
STID_S   2 Months SA STID_S  2 months SA
STID_E   36 Months STID_E  2 months HAEP
STID_L   36 Months LES STID_L  36 months LES
STID_D   6 Months STID_D  12 months E '

Comment: But I needs to get rid of record 1 and 3 as WPR and WP column really matched there if I ignore the case

I did as follows as suggested but didn't work for me. Not sure, is there anything wrong what I have done

' SELECT full.[Doc Name], full.[WPR], full.[Source Doc Name], full.[WP]
FROM [full] LEFT JOIN NotMatch ON UCASE(full.[WPR])= UCASE(NotMatch.[WP])
WHERE (((NotMatch.[WP]) Is Null)); '

Comment: Sorry I got a problem with formatting the comments. Its not working for me

Comment: modify this: ON UCASE(full.[WPR]) = UCASE(NotMatch.[WP])

Comment: even with that change it didn't work. I believe something wrong with my logic. Let me check first and then come back